# python with statement with class methods: AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the with statement with a class I implemented. But I don't want the constructor of the class to be called.

I tried this:

```
class Model(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        # some code that uses class variable from child classes
        # should not be called with with syntax
        pass


    @classmethod
    def __enter__(cls):
        print('call enter')
        return cls

    @classmethod
    def __exit__(cls, *args):
        print('call exit')

with Model:
  print('inside with')
```

but i get the error: `AttributeError: __enter__`

I don't understand why i get this error (my class has an enter method). Is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: Would [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) help you?

Comment: Why do you want to use a class as a context manager, rather than an instance of a class? (Ignoring the fact that `Model` itself is an instance of `ABCMeta`.)

Comment: `Model.__init__` depending on anything from a subclass is somewhat suspect to begin with.

Comment: @chepner
Why Model.__init__ depends on child classes class variables ?
I'm building an ORM. Child classes corresponds to db tables.
For instance, i have two tables: Comapny & Employee
I have the two corresponding classes.
Company and Employee class have a list of sql_fields (a field has a name and sql properties such as NON NULL)
When instantiating a Model (a company or an employee), I need to check that all non null attributes are defined.
This logic is shared between Company and employee, therefore it's implemented in Model Class that uses the sql_fields variable to check.

Comment: @chepner Why I use a class as context rather than instance ?
Because I can not instantiate Model, I can not use instance of class model as context.
Why I need to use a context ? The Model class is responsible for sql executions. For instance the Model class implements insert method using sql_fields child class variables. I need a context manager because if I want to run multiple insert, I want to open a db connection only once.

Comment: I'm not a python senior developper, If you think this it's a bad design, I'm open to any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` on the classes' class.

```
class MyType(type):
    def __enter__(cls):
        print('call enter')
        return cls

    def __exit__(cls, *args):
        print('call exit')

class Model(metaclass=MyType):
    pass
```

Demo:

```
>>> with Model:
...     pass
call enter
call exit
```

`Model` is an *instance* of `MyType`, the latter providing the magic methods.

Comment: is there a way to add parameters to __enter__ method in your solution? when i try to do so, python is ungry about that Model() receives no arguments.

Comment: @Bravhek see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109507/pass-argument-to-enter).

Answer (score -2):

This should work.

```
with Model() as m:
    print('inside with')
```

output:

```
call enter
inside with
call exit
```